# Puxar o echo do php para dentro de uma div, sem refresh

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho uma div no html, ela está com display none, eu preencho o form e os dados vão para um arquivo .php e o mesmo me da um echo dizendo que os dados foram inseridos no banco, só que eu queria que quando o php desse esse echo essa div que eu tenho pegasse a mensagem e exibisse.

HTML:

```
           <form id="form_pergunta" action="php/envia.php" Method="POST">
  <!--pergunta!-->
  <label for="input">Pergunta</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
  <input type="text" name="pergunta" data-placement="bottom" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Quem é Jeová, com base no Biblia Ensina Pg. 10, Cap: 5?" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="valida_pergunta" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Preencha o campo Pergunta
  </div>
  <!--pergunta!-->
  <!--resposta!-->
  <label for="input">Resposta:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-circle" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
  <input type="text" name="resposta" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: É Deus." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="valida_resposta" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Preencha o campo Resposta
  </div>
  <!--resposta!-->
  <!--Desafio!-->
  <label for="input">Desafio:</label>
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
  <input type="text" name="desafio" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex: Fique 10 segundos pulando num pé só." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
  </div><br>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" id="valida_desafio" role="alert">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Preencha o campo Desafio
  </div>
  <!--Desafio!-->



  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="select">Selecione a Dificuldade</label>
  <select class="form-control" name="dificuldade">
  <option value="1">Fácil</option>
  <option value="2">Médio</option>
  <option value="3">Difícil</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <center><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" value="Enviar" id="enviar"></center><br><br>
  </form>
```

PHP:

```
  <?php
    $pergunta = $_POST ['pergunta'];
    $resposta = $_POST ['resposta'];
    $dificuldade = $_POST ['dificuldade'];
    $desafio = $_POST ['desafio'];
    $msg;

    switch ($dificuldade) {
       case '1':
        $dificuldade = "Facil";
        break;
       case '2':
        $dificuldade = "Medio";
        break;
       case '3':
        $dificuldade = "Dificil";
       break;
    }

    try{
          $conexao = new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=teocratico;charset=utf8","root","");
     } catch (PDOException $erro){
       echo "Não foi possível conectar ao banco ". $erro->getMessage();

     }

    try {
    $insert =  $conexao-> prepare ("INSERT INTO perguntas (pergunta,  resposta, dificuldade, desafio) VALUES (

       :pergunta,
       :resposta,
       :dificuldade,
       :desafio
        )");
      $insert-> bindParam (':pergunta', $pergunta);
      $insert-> bindParam (':resposta', $resposta);
      $insert-> bindParam (':dificuldade', $dificuldade);
      $insert-> bindParam (':desafio', $desafio);
      $insert-> execute();

      $msg = "Pergunta enviada com Sucesso";
      echo $msg;
         } catch (Exception $erro) {
       echo "Não foi possivel enviar os dados" . $erro->getMessage();

     }
     ?>
```

JAVASCRIPT QUE VALIDA O FORM:

```
//Executar todo nosso JS quando o DOM estiver pronto. Por isso o Onload
```

window.onload = function(){

var button = document.getElementById("enviar"); // pega o valor do botao
var form = document.getElementById("form_pergunta"); //pega o form da pergunta todo
button.addEventListener("click", function(e){
if(validar(form)) form.submit();
});/*Com acesso a isso, podemos executar uma função a cada vez que o botão for clicado, para isso
vamos usar o addEventListener() no botão e colocar a seguinte lógica:
CASO A FUNÇÃO VALIDAR RETORNE VERDADEIRA, DÊ UM SUBMIT NO FORMULÁRIO*/

//Agora a função validar. Esta irá receber um parâmetro que é o próprio formulário que recuperamos acima.
function validar (form_pergunta){
var pergunta = form_pergunta.pergunta.value;
var resposta = form_pergunta.resposta.value;
var desafio = form_pergunta.desafio.value;
var passou = true;
if(pergunta ==""){
document.getElementById("valida_pergunta").style.display = "flex";
passou = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById("valida_pergunta").style.display = "none";
}
if (resposta == "") {
document.getElementById("valida_resposta").style.display ="flex";
passou = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById('valida_resposta').style.display = "none";
}
if (desafio ==""){
document.getElementById("valida_desafio").style.display = "flex";
passou = false;
} else {
  document.getElementById("valida_desafio").style.display = "none";
}
return passou;

}

}

Comment: Você precisa usar AJAX, veja se esta resposta lhe ajuda...http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/163498/%C3%89-poss%C3%ADvel-fazer-submit-sem-dar-refresh-e-sem-jquery/163505#163505

Comment: A..........j.........a..........x

Comment: Não precisa de ajax necessário. Basta replicar o código da div na resposta.

Comment: Eu to puxando de uma action externa, os scipts não estao no mesmo doc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Envia os dados do `form` sem refresh e com "validação"; Captura a resposta do `php` em `resp` e preenche a `div`; Mostra o botão de refresh para renovar o `form`

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#refresh').click(function () {
        window.location = window.location;
    });
    // Comportamento do botao de envio do FORM
    $('#enviar').click(function () {
        if(validar() === true){
            // Se a validacao passar, carrega os dados do FORM e envia
            $.post(
                $("#form_pergunta").attr("action"),// Captura o ACTION do FORM
                $("#form_pergunta").serialize() // Captura os campos do FORM 
            )
            // Se enviar com sucesso, retorna a resposta do PHP
            .done(function (resp) {
                $("#success").attr('class','alert alert-success');
                $("#success").html(resp); //Preenche a DIV com a resp
                $('#success').show(); //Mostra a DIV
                $("#form_pergunta input").prop("disabled", true);
                $("#form_pergunta select").prop("disabled", true);
                $('#enviar').hide(); //oculta o botao de envio
                $('#refresh').show(); //Mostra o botao de refresh
            })
            // Se o envio falhar, retorna uma msg de erro
            .fail(function (resp) {
                $("#success").attr('class','alert alert-danger'); //Muda o CSS da DIV
                $("#success").html('Falha no envio!'); //Preenche a DIV com a msg
                $('#success').show(); //Mostra a DIV
            });
        } else {

        }
    });
});
// Validacao do FORM ao enviar
function validar() {
    var passou = true;
    if ($('#pergunta').val() === "") {
        $('#valida_pergunta').show();
        passou = false;
    } else {
        $('#valida_pergunta').hide();
    }
    if ($('#resposta').val() === "") {
        $('#valida_resposta').show();
        passou = false;
    } else {
        $('#valida_resposta').hide();
    }
    if ($('#desafio').val() === "") {
        $('#valida_desafio').show();
        passou = false;
    } else {
        $('#valida_desafio').hide();
    }
    return passou;
}
</script>
```

Comment: A parte de envio do form e que evita o envio com Enter eu n entendi muito bem, eu vi alguns codigos como esse aqui ó: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/174883/formul%C3%A1rio-de-contato-com-ajax-sem-refresh

Comment: Eu tentei usar e não consegui, o meu problema não está sendo validar ou enviar, eu só quero que ao enviar com sucesso os dados para o banco, ele me de um retorno na div de sucesso. ou pelo menos pegue o echo do php e me jogue nessa div.

Comment: Mas é **exatamente** isso que esse código faz. Qual é a sua dúvida?

Comment: Ok, acho que o erro foi meu, vou testar novamente, pera ai.

Comment: eu fiz o código colocando os dados do meu HTML, só que agora ele me gera um novo form quando eu clico pra enviar.

Comment: e não envia mais nada., nem valida

Comment: Só pra esclarecer: você quer que isso funcione **sem refresh**, não é? Edite a pergunta e mostre o seu `FORM` pra eu adaptar o o `JavaScript`.

Comment: Isso, Eu tenho uma div pra cada campo e uma pra quando for com sucesso todas elas estão com display none, se na hora de validar, os campos estiverem vazios, ele muda o display da div, e ela fica visivel, eu queria que quando ele conseguisse enviar o form e o php conseguisse colocar as coisas no banco, ele mostrasse a div que fala "Dados enviados com sucesso"

Comment: :D Mas é exatamente isso que a minha resposta faz. Você só não está conseguindo adaptar no seu código. Mostre o `FORM` e eu faço as adaptações e explico o que foi feito, ok?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51377/discussion-between-tiago-silveira-and-shutupmagda).